# Excel Autofill is increasing numbers but not columns

Tags: excel

I'm trying to reformat my excel and therefore i wanted to use the autofill function (by dragging)

```
Kurs    Jahr    Monat       Bewerbungen Einstellungen   Gespräche
FI      2004    Juli           0              0            0
FI      2004    August         0              0            0
FI      2004    September      0              0            0
```

This is my desired result. The source has another format. Therefore for row 1 I have the following entries:

```
=D1 =D2 =D3 ...
=E1 =E2 =E3 ...
```

When i try to drag this list down i will not receive =F1 ... next, but =D4 ... so basically the number is increasing in an odd way. What I need is an increase of the column (D -> E -> F...)

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question, but isnt that how it supposed to work?  If you drag down the row numbers increase.  Dragging horizontally increases the column letters.

Comment: Ans i need the opposite :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not entirely sure I understand your question, but I think what you want is paste special > transpose.

Say your data is formatted like so

```
Kurs           FI       FI       FI
Jahr           2004     2004     2004
Monat          Juli     August  September
Bewerbungen     0       0        0
Einstellungen   0       0        0
Gespräche       0       0        0
```

Just highlight the entire selection, right click on your sheet somewhere, select "paste special", and then select the "transpose" option.  The end result will be your desired result.